# VueJS & Vuetify - How to use JS variables in Sass

Tags: vue.js, sass, vuetify.js

Using VueJS, I need to display different colors for each user. The color depends on the user settings.

In my vuetify.js, I have:

```
export default new Vuetify({
  theme: {
    themes: {
      light: {
        primary: user.colorMain ? user.colorMain : '#F39200',
```

It works when I use:

```
$vuetify.theme.themes.light.primary
```

in my components.

But I would need to override the Sass variables too, in my variable.scss file:

```
$primary-color: #f39200;
```

Is there a way to override my sass variables dynamically from a JS variable?

Answer (score 2):

tl:dr; **no, it's not possible to change Sass variable values at runtime**, because they no longer exist at runtime. They have been translated into plain (static) CSS.
However, like with any CSS values, you can override them.

Sass variables are only used to pre-process SCSS into CSS at compile time. The result of compilation is static CSS, loaded when the app is mounted. In simpler terms, the app doesn't know that CSS was preprocessed from an SCSS source. For it, it's static CSS.

Example:

```
$primary-color: #f39200;
.my-button { color: $primary-color; }
```

will output the following CSS code:

```
.my-button { color: #f39200; }
```

---

If you want runtime dynamic values, you have two options:

1. **Use CSS variables**.
   Produce the following CSS, via your preferred method (from SCSS/CSS/Stylus, doesn't matter, as long as this is the output):

```
.my-button { color: var(--primary-color); }
```

... and, anywhere in the chain of parents or on the element itself:

```
<div :style="{'--primary-color': someDynamicColor }" />
```

With the above in place, when you change `someDynamicColor`, at runtime, the `color` changes in DOM.

2. **Use Vue3's ["reactive styles"](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/pull/231)** feature:

```
<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({ someDynamicColor: 'red' })
}
</script>
<style>
  .my-button {
    color: v-bind('someDynamicColor');
  }
</style>
```

Again, this is dynamic. If you change/animate the value of `someDynamicColor` on the element, the CSS value will be applied in DOM. It doesn't have to be a `data` prop, it can be a `prop`, `computed`, ...

---

**Important notes:**

- when using CSS variables (1.), the value of `var(--primary-color)` doesn't have to be set in the same component, but it has to be set on a direct ancestor of the current DOM element.
- when using reactive styles (2.), the prop/computed referenced in CSS/SCSS has to be set in the current component's scope.
- Under the hood, reactive styles also use CSS variables: they're uniquely named at compile time.
- CSS variables don't use specificity. If you override the value set by some grand-parent at parent level, the child has no way of reading the grand-parent's value, regardless of specificity. If you have such a case, you probably want to manage the grandparent value in external state and provide it to both grand-parent and child.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, indeed it's not possible, I was thinking of some possibility with vuetify, but no. Reactive styles are really interesting, I can't upgrade unfortunately.. for now I will use some inline CSS and add custom CSS in head.. Thanks